# Google Play Console Pre-launch report - memory

Tags: android, performance, memory, google-play-console, prelaunch

Help me understand how to interpret (and improve my app performance) using the memory chart in the Google Play Console pre-launch reports.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory profiler in the Google Play console pre-launch report is just there to let you know if you have an obvious serious problem. Eg suppose the memory usage jumped up and never came down again you might know you had a memory leak. The other thing it could tell you if your memory usage is much higher than it should be for your app. But without knowing the details of what your app does, it is hard to know how much memory it should need.

In the graph you show:

- there are no obvious quick memory leaks (jumps up without jumping down) except at startup which is expected
- the memory usage (about 150M) seems high, but it depends what your app is doing.
- the memory usage is trending upwards which might indicate an ongoing slow memory leak, but the trend is very slow

To investigate where your memory is going you should use [a Memory profiler and one comes with Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler.html).